# Zend framework ACL not fetching 'Role' column from database

Tags: php, zend-framework, acl

I'm currently working on a project which requires ACL,The problem is 'role' column is not getting identified.I've all the roles predefined in the 'users' table.

AuthPlugin file

```
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    // If user is not logged in and is not requesting login page
    // - redirect to login page.
    if (!$auth->hasIdentity()
    && $request->getControllerName() != $loginController
    && $request->getActionName()     != $loginAction) {

        $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector');
        $redirector->gotoSimpleAndExit($loginAction, $loginController);
    }

    // User is logged in or on login page.

    if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
         $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
        $acl = $registry->get('acl');
        $identity = $auth->getIdentity();
        $isAllowed = $acl->isAllowed($identity->role,
        $request->getControllerName(),
        $request->getActionName());
        if (!$isAllowed) {
        $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector');
        $redirector->gotoUrlAndExit('/');
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

ACL config

```
<?php
$acl = new Zend_Acl();

$roles  = array('Administrator', 'User');
$controllers = array('cart', 'index', 'user', 'purchase');
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
    $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role($role));
}
foreach ($controllers as $controller) {
    $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource($controller));
}
$acl->allow('Administrator'); 
$acl->allow('User');
$acl->deny('User', 'Administrator');

$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$registry->set('acl', $acl);
```

controller

```
  public function indexAction()
{
    $form = new Application_Form_Login();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            if ($this->_process($form->getValues())) {
                $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index');
            }
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}

protected function _process($values)
{
    $adapter = $this->_getAuthAdapter();
    $adapter->setIdentity($values['username']);
    $adapter->setCredential($values['password']);

    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
    if ($result->isValid()) {
        $user = $adapter->getResultRowObject();
        $auth->getStorage()->write($user);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

protected function _getAuthAdapter()
{   
    $dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbAdapter);

    $authAdapter->setTableName('users')
                ->setIdentityColumn('username')
                ->setIdentity($username)
                ->setCredentialColumn('password')
                ->setCredentialTreatment('MD5(?)');
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
    if ($result->isValid()) {
        $data = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject(null, 'password'); // without password
        $auth->getStorage()->write($data);
    return $authAdapter;
}
```

when i try to login i get an error message as

```
Message: A value for the identity was not provided prior to authentication with Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable.
```

Please tell me a way by which i can get the 'role' from the users table.

Comment: `print_r($identity);` either you dont have role or invalid role is there.